# The Instance Of Entity Type X Cannot Be Tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am working on EF Core 7 where I can include a Json inside my entity as a table column:

```
builder.Entity<ShoppingChannels>().OwnsMany(s => s.ChannelProducts, options =>
        {
            options.ToJson();
        });
```

I am trying to limit the number of json elements to 50 using the following code:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var shoppingChannelsList = await context.ShoppingChannels
                                            .ToListAsync();

    foreach (var channelId in shoppingChannelsList)
    {
        var filteredChannelProducts = channelId.ChannelProducts                        
                    .Take(50)
                    .ToList();

        channelId.ChannelProducts = filteredChannelProducts;
    }

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

But this code does not work and raises an exception on `SaveChanges`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'ChannelProducts' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ShoppingChannelsId: fc470701-f01a-
> 4f6b-b424-379edb315ada, Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When replacing owned entities, modify the properties without changing the instance or detach the previous owned entity entry first.'

I modified the code to remove records one by one, and this worked:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var shoppingChannelsList = await context.ShoppingChannels
                                            .ToListAsync();

    foreach (var channelId in shoppingChannelsList)
    {
        var productsToRemove = channelId.ChannelProducts
                    .Skip(50)
                    .ToList();

        foreach (var product in productsToRemove)
        {
            channelId.ChannelProducts.Remove(product);
        }
    }

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

These are the model classes:

```
public class ShoppingChannels
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public List<ChannelProducts> ChannelProducts { get; set; } 
}

public class ChannelProducts
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a normal behavior of Entity Framework Core 7, or I am missing some logic in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure about complexities with the ToJson, but you definitely do not want to do something like setting a navigation collection in a loaded entity. Setters for collections should be private to avoid code like that. Why would there be more than 50 in the first place?  Bulk operations like this would be better done outside of EF executing directly against the database.

Comment: @StevePy because at the end of the day, ChannelProducts is saved as a string, that's why I thought navigation might be fine.. I guess not.